# image = vision_client.image( AttributeError: 'ImageAnnotatorClient' object has no attribute 'image'

Tags: python, google-api, google-vision

```
import io,os

# Imports the Google Cloud client library
from google.cloud import vision
# Instantiates a client (Change the line below******)
vision_client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient('my-key.json')   

# The name of the image file to annotate (Change the line below 'image_path.jpg' ******)
file_name = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__),
    'image_path.jpg') 

# Loads the image into memory
with io.open(file_name, 'rb') as image_file:
    content = image_file.read()
    image = vision_client.image(
        content=content)

# Performs label detection on the image file
labels = image.detect_labels()

print('Labels:')
for label in labels:
    print(label.description)
```

## python 3.6.5 on windows

this code example gives me the error mention in the title, is anyone knows how to fix that?

Comment: might wanna take a look at this https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/0.32.0/vision/gapic/v1/api.html

Comment: maybe you can tell me what wrong in my code example?

Comment: anyone else? I just need to know how to fix my code

Comment: it's right there... `ImageAnnotatorClient` simply has no atrribute named `image`, which is why `image = vision_client.image` does not work

Comment: so how can I solve it? what to change for?

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
import io
import os
# Imports the Google Cloud client library
from google.cloud import vision
from google.cloud.vision import types
# Instantiates a client
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
# The name of the image file to annotate
file_name = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__),
    'resources/wakeupcat.jpg')

# Loads the image into memory
with io.open(file_name, 'rb') as image_file:
    content = image_file.read()
image = types.Image(content=content)
# Performs label detection on the image file
response = client.label_detection(image=image)
labels = response.label_annotations
print('Labels:')
for label in labels:
    print(label.description)
```

Answer (score 0):

There were some things wrong with your code, but i think i found all of them.

```
import os, io
from google.cloud import vision

vision_client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient('my-key.json')   

file_name = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'image_path.jpg') 

with io.open(file_name, 'rb') as image_file:
    content = image_file.read()

labels = vision_client.label_detection({'content': content})
labels = labes.label_annotations()

print('Labels:')
for label in labels:
    print(label.description)
```

Comment: first of all - I also used io module. secondly you should write 'vision' and not 'Vision'. after I fixed all that I got bunch of errors so you did not answered to my question as well and you did not helped me to fix them..

Comment: another any help? come on guys it must be easy to someone who work with this module before...

Comment: Thank you! 
after I changed I got that errors -

 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_file.py", line 11, in <module>
    labels = vision_client.label_detection(content).label_annotations()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-

Comment: is there something new?